# How do make user editable file of settings in a C# windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I'm creating my first Windows Forms Application, and one requirement is that there is some sort of config file, which the client can edit in notepad. For example, the config file may have an XML structure of:

```
<languages>
  <language name="English" />
</languages>
```

The application accesses the file when generating a combobox of languages on a form. If the client wishes, he could go in and add another `<language>` node.

I've tried to use the app.config file, with a custom configuration section. When I publish the application and then install it, the [appname].exe.config.deploy file in the [appname]/Application Files/[appname_version]/ folder is editable, but the application doesn't seem to be aware of the edits. In other words, if I add another `<language>` node, the application doesn't display it on the form.

I'm not sure if I'm actually doing any of this correctly. Are users supposed to be able to edit the config.deploy file? If not, what is the correct usage scenario? I'm thinking back to the old days of games having .ini files, which you could edit in Notepad!

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create these configurable controls?

Comment: Technically, I could just package a .txt or .xml file with the application, and just use the IO file library to read it. But I'm worried that when the application gets installed, that file would need to also be installed to the same folder. Also, if a user tried to edit that file, they'd have to find the installation folder, which seems to be in a _really_ weird path, like Users/[User]/App_Data/strangelocation

Comment: @Andrey Atapin:
    MyConfigSection config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myconfig") as MyConfigSection;
            foreach (LanguageElement le in config.Languages)
            {
                ddlLanguage.Items.Add(le.Name);
            }

, where MyConfigSection is a class which overrides System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your xml file to the project > select file & go to property window > Build Action as content > copy to output directory to Copy if newer or always. Change your code to read languages list from xml file located at exe folder location

Comment: The program files directories are read only in Windows 7, better to put it in UserData

Comment: How does the client, after running setup.exe, know where the application has been installed to so that he can go edit the xml file?

Comment: You can give button to open the xml file to edit, or show the location somewhere on winform.

Comment: The thing is this: The application is for employees of my client to capture new users. Only the client must be able to edit the config file, not the employees, so I don't want it to be editable from inside the application. You may ask, "couldn't the employees simply edit the config file in notepad?". The client says not to worry, because the employees aren't particularly computer literate, so only he would know about the config file for editing. So, how do I tell the client where the config file is located so that he can edit it?

Comment: Why not give an interface on the form to edit the languages? From the UI if some adds or remove new language, add / remove them to/from xml, and then populate new list based on languages contained in XML. And show the edit option when user is not employee. If you do not have authentication, do a trick. Place another file with arbitrary name in the same location. If that file exist, allow them to edit, else disable it, and give this file to client only and not to employee

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My app doesn't have authentication, and employees and client use the same machine, so your proposal about the file is not necessarily very user friendly. I just feel though that there _should_ be a more direct way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Your app must know what type of user it is to have this feature. If both client and employee use same machine but different profile, u can check user by windows active directory. Otherwise store XML to some fixed location and read the file from there. Tell client to go to that folder and modify when needed.

Comment: OK, storing XML in a fixed location like root sounds like a better solution. Thanks for your help!